# Pre-fill a form (no control over form code)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm using a form plugin / addon where I don't have control over how the form is generated.

The form generates HTML which looks like this:

```
<form>
<label>First Name</label><input name="Question25" type="text" value="" />
<input class="formBlockSubmitButton" name="add" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I would like to prefill some of the form values but I **can't** write, say

```
<input name="Question25" type="text" value="<?php echo $my_value; ?>" />
```

Because the form addon generates that HTML. I can write PHP or Javascript before this block, is there a way to search for an input with a name of "Question25" and then prefill it when the block comes up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use jQuery and the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('input[name="Question25"]').val('some value');
    });
</script>
```

and if the value must come from the server:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var obj = <?php echo json_encode(array('value' => $my_value)); ?>;
        $('input[name="Question25"]').val(obj.value);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have a question...why the json_encode and not just var obj = <?php echo $my_value; ?> ?

Comment: Because if `$my_value` equals for example `John d'Arcy` you will end up `var obj = 'John d'Arcy';` which as you can notice is pretty broken javascript. The `json_encode` method ensures that no matter what characters you have inside this string, they will be properly serialized into javascript. You should ensure to always properly encode your data.

Answer (score 1):

You can emit all the values you'd like to search as an array of fieldname/values, and then emit a function that tries to map those values to those fields.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var values = [{fieldName:'Question25', value:'MyValue'}]; // iterate through your values in PHP and generate the {fieldName:'value',value:'value'} object

$(function() {
    $.each(values, function(index, item) {
         $('input[name=' + item.fieldName + ']').val(item.value);
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var value='<?php echo $my_value; ?>'
$("input:text[name='Question25']").val(value);
```

use something like this

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript. With jQuery, you could do something along the lines of:

```
$("input[name=Question25]").val(my_value);
```

You can then insert PHP vairables into the Javascript with echo, load them with AJAX, or whatever you need.